# When to use Event-tracking and when to use Page-view tracking on AJAX-calls

Tags: events, google-analytics

Well, my question is, which I should use when?

For example I use AJAX calls for all my form submissions - both user creations, advertisements creations, editing advertisements and so on.

Is there any golden rule about when to use event-tracking and when to add a page-view manually? :)

Is there any disadvantages in one of them regarding to e.g. goal tracking and so on? :)

Thansk in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is that you can't have funnels with event based goals, so if you want to track at which point people drop out of a multi-step process you would need virtual pageviews.

Other than that there are only "best practices" which are somewhat open to interpretation - I use virtual pageviews when I update significant parts of the content, but your idea of what is significant might be different than mine. So you need to get everyone who uses your tracking implementation on board - they need to be aware what parts of the site are tracked in which way, especially if they try to compare your site with another - and you should have extensive, regularly updated documentation.

There is more than one way to do it, so it's important that your way is well documemted and reproducible.